# List of setspn service classes and their meanings

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I am trying to set up my Java tomcat service to be authenticated using Kerberos (Negotiate SSO) in MS AD. For this it is necessary to create SPN.

In the documentation of setspn on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241.aspx I have found brief description of this command. Unfortunatelly I was unable to find description of possible values and their meanings for service classes. Can somebody provide list of common service classes and their usage ? What is difference between MSSQLSvc/myserver and HTTP/myserver or HOST/myserver ?

From the name I think, the MSSQLSvc is something related to SQL only, but when to use HTTP and when HOST ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such list, because for example you, as a software developer may create a new service, register it in ActiveDirectory under sPN: KULATAMICUDA/myservice@MY.DOMAIN, write your client, which looks for sPN KULATAMICUDA/myservice@MY.DOMAIN in ActiveDirectory in order to log into it.

In case of prefix HTTP, all web browsers construct SPNs in such a way, that they append to "HTTP/" host of the address, which user typed in. If you want your webserver to be found by them in ActiveDirectory, you register it under the HTTP/yourwebserver SPN.

By the way: SPNs are case sensitive!